# Angular 2 - Creating form in a subscription causes crash saying the formGroup is undefined

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I've got some data in my Firebase database, this data I want to apply to a form via `FormBuilder`. It works somewhat good but I get errors more often than not saying `formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.`.

What doesn't make sense is that when I apply new changes to the database which cause the subscription to fire, I get the error. Despite `this.settingsForm` being set before and after the subscription runs after updating.

Here's the subscription:

```
this.eventSubscription = this.af.database.object('/events/' + this.eventId).subscribe(
  (event: IEvent) => {

    const rsvp: IRSVP = event.rsvp;
    const settings: ISettings = event.settings;
    const tickets: ITickets = event.tickets;

    this.settingsForm = this.fb.group({
      collaborators: this.fb.array(settings.collaborators || []),
      isRSVPOpen: settings.isRSVPOpen,
      isAutoApproveToGuestlist: settings.isAutoApproveToGuestlist,
      rsvp: this.fb.group({
        latestDate: [rsvp.latestDate, [Validators.required]],
        latestTime: [rsvp.latestTime, [Validators.required]],
        guestLimit: [rsvp.guestLimit, [Validators.required]],
        isGuestPlusOne: rsvp.isGuestPlusOne,
        isAutoApproveToGuestlist: rsvp.isAutoApproveToGuestlist,
        isOnlyFacebookRSVP: rsvp.isOnlyFacebookRSVP,
        isBirthdayAndPhoneRequired: rsvp.isBirthdayAndPhoneRequired
      }),
      tickets: this.fb.group({
        info: this.fb.group({
          closingDate: tickets.info.closingDate,
          closingTime: tickets.info.closingTime
        }),
        types: this.fb.array(tickets.types || [])
      })
    });
  }
);
```

So what I'm wondering is why is this happening and how can I prevent it? Can't I init the form like this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `*ngIf="settingsForm"`.

If you have a FormGroup that has not been initialized, it cannot be used in the template. For example, the following will not work if `settingsForm` has not been initialized:

```
<form [formGroup]="settingsForm ">
  <input formControlName="name" />
</form>
```

Do this instead:

```
<form *ngIf="settingsForm" [formGroup]="settingsForm ">
  <input formControlName="name" />
</form>
```