# Building form after subscribe gives "expect formgroup instance" error

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to build a page in angular 6 containing a form, who's `projects` dropdown is populated using data retrieved from the `REST` call. When i test everything without a subscribe using hardcoded data the form works perfectly. However, when I add the rest call and build the form inside the subscribe scope, it gives me a `FormGroup` error 3 - 4 times in the console:

> ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

I am not sure why the form works perfectly without subscribe call, maybe an issue with async calls?

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42091090/angular-2-creating-form-in-a-subscription-causes-crash-saying-the-formgroup-is) solution but it doesn't work for me, only removes the form altogether

**Note**: I also have a few other pages that implement this but none of them had this issue.

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { TranslatePipe } from 'src/app/pipes/translate/translate.pipe';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { DynamicTextFieldService } from 'src/app/services/dynamic-loading/dynamic-text-field/dynamic-text-field.service';
import { DynamicDropdownService } from 'src/app/services/dynamic-loading/dynamic-dropdown/dynamic-dropdown.service';
import { DynamicTextAreaService } from 'src/app/services/dynamic-loading/dynamic-text-area/dynamic-text-area.service';
import { CustomSearchService } from 'src/app/services/search/custom-search/custom-search.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-knowledge-base-create',
  templateUrl: './knowledge-base-create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./knowledge-base-create.component.scss']
})
export class KnowledgeBaseCreateComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {

  @ViewChild('f1', { read: ViewContainerRef }) f1;
  @ViewChild('f2', { read: ViewContainerRef }) f2;
  @ViewChild('f3', { read: ViewContainerRef }) f3;
  @ViewChild('f4', { read: ViewContainerRef }) f4;

  kbForm: FormGroup;

  projectsList: any;

  constructor(private location: Location,
    private translate: TranslatePipe,
    private dynamictextfield: DynamicTextFieldService,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private dynamicdropdown: DynamicDropdownService,
    private dynamictextarea: DynamicTextAreaService,
    private search: CustomSearchService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.search.searchCall("PP_1_Projects", "", "", true).subscribe(
      response => {
        response = response.records;
        this.projectsList = response;
        this.buildForm();
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

  buildForm() {
    this.kbForm = this.fb.group({
      'f1': ['', Validators.required],
      'f2': ['', Validators.required],
      'f3': ['', Validators.required],
      'f4': ['', Validators.required]
    })
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.buildf1();
    this.buildf2();
    this.buildf3();
    this.buildf4();
  }

  goBack() {
    this.location.back();
  }

  buildf1() {
    let data = {
      reference: this.f1,
      type: "text",
      class: "form-control",
      placeholder: "Article Name", //TODO: change to translate
      id: "f1",
      autoComplete: false,
      formControlName: "f1",
      group: this.kbForm
    }
    this.dynamictextfield.loadTextField(data);
  }

  buildf2() {
    let data = this.projectsList;
    let array = {
      reference: this.f2,
      id: "f2",
      formControlName: "f2",
      group: this.kbForm,
      data: data,
      placeholder: "Select Project Name"
    }
    this.dynamicdropdown.loadDropdown(array);
  }

  buildf3() {
    let data = [
      {
        "name": "New"
      },
      {
        "name": "Open"
      },
      {
        "name": "Closed"
      }
    ]

    let array = {
      reference: this.f3,
      id: "f3",
      formControlName: "f3",
      group: this.kbForm,
      data: data,
      placeholder: "Select Status"
    }
    this.dynamicdropdown.loadDropdown(array);
  }

  buildf4() {
    let data = {
      reference: this.f4,
      placeholder: "Enter any notes here..", //TODO: change to translate
      id: "f4",
      formControlName: "f4",
      group: this.kbForm
    }
    this.dynamictextarea.loadTextArea(data);
  }


}
```

**component.html**

```
<div>
  <app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
  <app-side-nav></app-side-nav>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <app-button description="{{ 'pages[knowledge_base][buttons][go_back]' | translate }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-md custom" (callFunction)="goBack()"></app-button>
    <div class="card-group">
      <div class="card p-4">
        <form [formGroup]="kbForm">
          <h2 class="col-md-6">Create New Knowledge Base Article</h2>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div #f1 class="input"></div>
            <div #f2 class="input"></div>
            <div #f3 class="input"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div #f4 class="input"></div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The error is clear: you're trying to use `[formGroup]="kbForm"` but `kbForm` is undefined unti the search finally succeeds. So either use *ngIf to avoid displaying the form while kbForm is undefined, or build your form immediately, without waiting for the search to succeed.

Comment: I tried to add `*ngIf`, but then the form disappears altogether, where the console says: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'createComponent' of undefined` (I am using componentFactoryResolver for rendering components). I cannot build the form immediately because the values of my dropdown are dependent on the result from the `REST` call. Could there be a workaround for this?

Comment: That's the whole point of ngIf: to avoid adding something in the dom. You can't display a form if the model of the form doesn't exist. So, once again, either you don't display the form, or you display it with an unpopulated dropdown that will populate later.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround, the `this.buildf2();` function was using the data from the response being saved in `projectsList`, so instead of adding `this.buildForm();` to the response group I added this function. It rendered the div properly with the updated response.

Like so:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { TranslatePipe } from 'src/app/pipes/translate/translate.pipe';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { DynamicTextFieldService } from 'src/app/services/dynamic-loading/dynamic-text-field/dynamic-text-field.service';
import { DynamicDropdownService } from 'src/app/services/dynamic-loading/dynamic-dropdown/dynamic-dropdown.service';
import { DynamicTextAreaService } from 'src/app/services/dynamic-loading/dynamic-text-area/dynamic-text-area.service';
import { CustomSearchService } from 'src/app/services/search/custom-search/custom-search.service';
import { CustomValidators } from 'src/app/views/forgot-password/reset-password/custom-validators';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-knowledge-base-create',
  templateUrl: './knowledge-base-create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./knowledge-base-create.component.scss']
})
export class KnowledgeBaseCreateComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {

  @ViewChild('f1', { read: ViewContainerRef }) f1;
  @ViewChild('f2', { read: ViewContainerRef }) f2;
  @ViewChild('f3', { read: ViewContainerRef }) f3;
  @ViewChild('f4', { read: ViewContainerRef }) f4;

  projectsList: any;

  kbForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private location: Location,
    private translate: TranslatePipe,
    private dynamictextfield: DynamicTextFieldService,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private dynamicdropdown: DynamicDropdownService,
    private dynamictextarea: DynamicTextAreaService,
    private search: CustomSearchService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.buildForm(); //removed call from here, replaced with buildForm()
  }

  buildForm() {
    this.kbForm = this.fb.group({
      'f1': ['', Validators.required],
      'f2': ['', Validators.required],
      'f3': ['', Validators.required],
      'f4': ['', Validators.required]
    })
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.buildf1();
    this.buildf3();
    this.buildf4();
    this.retrieveProjectData(); //added function here, renders perfectly
  }

  retrieveProjectData() { //created this function instead, added to afterContentInit
    this.search.searchCall("PP_1_Projects", "", "", true).subscribe(
      response => {
        response = response.records;
        this.projectsList = response;
        this.buildf2();
        console.log(response);
      },
      error=>{
        console.log(error);
      }
    )
  }

  goBack() {
    this.location.back();
  }

  buildf1() {
    let data = {
      reference: this.f1,
      type: "text",
      class: "form-control",
      placeholder: "Article Name", //TODO: change to translate
      id: "f1",
      autoComplete: false,
      formControlName: "f1",
      group: this.kbForm
    }
    this.dynamictextfield.loadTextField(data);
  }

  buildf2() {
    let data: any;
    if (this.projectsList == undefined) {
      data = [
        {
          "name": ""
        }
      ]
    } else {
      data = this.projectsList;
    }

    let array = {
      reference: this.f2,
      id: "f2",
      formControlName: "f2",
      group: this.kbForm,
      data: data,
      placeholder: "Select Project Name"
    }
    this.dynamicdropdown.loadDropdown(array);
  }

  buildf3() {
    let data = [
      {
        "name": "New"
      },
      {
        "name": "Published"
      },
      {
        "name": "Unpublished"
      }
    ]

    let array = {
      reference: this.f3,
      id: "f3",
      formControlName: "f3",
      group: this.kbForm,
      data: data,
      placeholder: "Select Status"
    }
    this.dynamicdropdown.loadDropdown(array);
  }

  buildf4() {
    let data = {
      reference: this.f4,
      placeholder: "Enter any notes here..", //TODO: change to translate
      id: "f4",
      formControlName: "f4",
      group: this.kbForm
    }
    this.dynamictextarea.loadTextArea(data);
  }

  get form() {
    return this.kbForm.controls;
  }


}
```